# How Can i Show a list Vertically in ASP.net C# Using DataGrid Or DataList View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datagrid, datalist

I really don't know is it possible or not, any way i want to have a list in vertically view in ASP.net page. For Example the normal Grid/List is like this :

[image: The Normal DataGrid In ASP.net]

But I want to Grid/List be something like this :

[image: Vertical DataGrid]

Sorry To use previous image just in rotate view, but i believe you experts can figure my mean out.

Attention:I do not want to text show vertically exactly like picture.i want the position of field be vertical like this example picture.

So Please Help me.and let me use your knowledges
Thank evry one.

Comment: read [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1282115.aspx), I believe what you are looking for is a "matrix" format

Comment: [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ed13322f-ae87-4203-b76e-81d69887b00c/how-to-combine-datagirdview-cells-just-like-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html?forum=winformsdatacontrols) may also help, but to be honest I did not fully read it myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with the help of CSS. Add a new CSS class aur include these in your current CSS class for gridview :

```
 .box_rotate {
 -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
   -o-transform: rotate(270deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=270);  /* IE6,IE7 */
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=270)"; /* IE8 */
}
```

Set the Padding and margins after rotation.

Comment: not Helpful.i want to alien those with C# behind code or in configuring Grid/List Not in Css